# Vue-CLI-Service CPU Usage

Tags: vue.js, nginx, vue-cli-3

I have a dockerized vue-cli app which is being run on NGINX environment.

Any time the image container starts we are seeing the CPU usage climb to nearly 100% then drop then climb then drop again.

Apparently the offending item is "/app/node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service"

This is preventing the site from being reached and we are getting a 502 error.

Any idea what might be causing the problem.

I am happy to provide any other necessary information.

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development vue-cli-service serve --port 3000",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production vue-cli-service serve --port 3000"
  },
```

In vue.config.js

```
,
   devServer: {
      disableHostCheck: true
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the limited information you provided, it looks like you're running a development environment in production. What you should do instead is build a production bundle, which consists of static assets - .html, .js, .css files, images etc., and serve that using a web server like `nginx`. For more details you can read https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html .

Comment: I am bundling and deploying in similar way to what is described in the docs. I have added my dockerfile, package.json, and vue.config.js for reference.  It should be taking care of bundling and providing a production build.

Comment: You're still running `vue-cli-service` (which under the hood uses `webpack-dev-server`), even if you set `NODE_ENV=production`. You should instead be serving the built assets in the `dist` folder using `nginx` (or any other web server). Have you tried using the `Dockerfile` described in https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#docker-nginx ?

Comment: Thank you much.  I thought I had tried out the recommended setup previously but apparently not.  This is working like a charm now.